# Can I define a default value for ember-data model attributes?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I define an attribute for a model in ember-data, can I specify a default value?

The ember-data [model definition](https://github.com/emberjs/data#defining-models) suggests attributes are defined like this:

```
attributeName: DS.attr('number')
```

...with an optional second argument as an options hash. I've looked at [the code](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/attributes.js) but my code-reading skills aren't up to figuring out what attributes I can put in the options hash. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
attributeName: DS.attr('number', { default: 0 })
```

or

```
attributeName: DS.attr('boolean', { default: false })
```

?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You were close, it's `defaultValue`, see [attributes.js#L63-65](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/b4a415e1be4db3673a102b3fdc45b6bd22d46d59/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/attributes.js#L63-65).

Comment: Brilliant. I realized it couldn't be "default" because that's a JS reserved word.

Comment: Technically, it still could be "default", you'd just have to put it in quotes.

Comment: Would recommend linking to the usage guide and add the example into the answer :). https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/defining-models/#toc_options and @attr('boolean', { defaultValue: false }) verified;

Answer (score 4):

defaultValue doesn't work if the property is null. It only works for 'undefined' attributes. [See this](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/b4a415e1be4db3673a102b3fdc45b6bd22d46d59/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/attributes.js#L63-65)